# dataframe value modification randomly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume we have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'1':[0.1,0.2,0.05,0.6],'2':[0.2,0.4,0.1,0.06],'3':[0.5,0.4,0.05,0.1]})
```

or:

```
      1     2     3
0  0.10  0.20  0.50
1  0.20  0.40  0.40
2  0.05  0.10  0.05
3  0.60  0.06  0.10
```

Sum of columns are 0.95, 0.76, 1.05. The desired summation is 1.

**The goal:**

make every *column* add up to **1**. Some of the columns add to a number greater than one and some to a number smaller than one.

**Constraint:**

Add or subtract only from **one** member in each column.

**Desired output:**

The output should be something like this:

```
      1     2     3
0  0.15  0.20  0.50
1  0.20  0.40  0.40
2  0.05  0.10  0.05
3  0.60  0.30  0.05
```

Sum of all columns are now 1. However, only **one** element in each column has changed.

**My efforts:**

My plan has been to calculate how much a column is more/less than one as follows:

```
1-df.sum(axis=0)
```

which returns:

```
1    0.05
2    0.24
3   -0.05
dtype: float64
```

This will give us a series that contain the difference of each element and one.

I can select a random element of each column by:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(1))
```

which returned (YMMV since it is random selection):

```
      1    2    3
1   NaN  0.4  NaN
2  0.05  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  0.1
```

Now I cannot figure out how to add these values to a random member of each column.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: provide expected output and your efforts.

Comment: Thank you @AkshayNevrekar The question edited as asked.

Comment: How do you decide which member to choose for adding or subtracting?

Comment: Randomly is fine.

Comment: Is there an implicit assumption that each element in your dataframe has to be in the range 0<x<1? Otherwise you could simply add/subtract your series difference from the first row.

Answer (score 2):

Using for loop you can do it.

```
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'1':[0.1,0.2,0.05,0.6],'2':[0.2,0.4,0.1,0.06],'3':[0.5,0.4,0.05,0.1]})

for i in df.columns:
    s=df[i].sum()
    x = random.randint(0,len(df))
    if s > 1:
        df.iloc[x][i] = df.iloc[x][i] - (s-1)

    elif s < 1 :
        df.iloc[x][i] = df.iloc[x][i] + (1-s)
```

output:

```
    1       2       3
0   0.1     0.20    0.50
1   0.2     0.40    0.35
2   0.1     0.34    0.05
3   0.6     0.06    0.10
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
# don't use this in practice.
# I only have it here to make
# my results reproduceable
np.random.seed((3, 1415))

v = df.values
n, m = v.shape

# Crux of process is to choose m random numbers from 0-n
a = np.random.choice(np.arange(n), m)
b = np.arange(m)

# Now modify just those points with the differrence you found
v[a, b] += 1 - v.sum(0)

# reassign back to df
# in some circumstances, assigning to v will have done to the trick.
# but not in all circumstances.  This is to ensure it gets done.
df.loc[:] = v.round(2)

df

      1    2    3
0  0.15  0.2  0.5
1  0.20  0.4  0.4
2  0.05  0.1 -0.0
3  0.60  0.3  0.1
```